# External style sheet for if IE containing all the IE style sheet rules

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Im working on a responsive site that uses quite allot of ccs3 and JS, the site has lots of fall backs so it works cross browser back to IE8. For almost all of the IE versions ive had a write specific IE browser code like this in the `<head>` of each page

/*CSS STYLES*/

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
  <style>
    /*CSS STYLES*/
  </style>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lt IE 8]>
  <style>
    /*CSS STYLES*/
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Instead of doing this as it takes up room in the head of each page is it possible to do something like this :

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
      <style>
        /*Go to a style sheet where all the above code is*/
      </style>
    <![endif]-->
```

What im trying to do here is allow IE to open up a separate style sheet containing all of the above rules for all the IE browser, rather than having to set an external style sheet for each if IE block in the `<head>`

Answer (score 0):

The same way a normal stylesheet would be referenced.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel=stylesheet href="YOUR_FILE_HERE.css">
<![endif]-->
```